# Unable to Paste a column except 1st row in different excel workbook using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do simple copy paste task of a range. I am looking for a match of header in two excel sheets and when match occur I am trying to copy that column except 1st row to the different excel with same sheet name. I am able to copy paste complete column but I don't want to copy 1st row which is header. 
Please advice

```
Set Wb1 = Workbooks(Wb1name)
Sheetname = Wb1.ActiveSheet.Name

Set Wb2 = Workbooks("Worksheet2.xlsm")


'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
l1Col = Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
l1Row = Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
l2Col = Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
l2Row = Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To l1Col
    For j = 1 To l2Col
        If "       " & Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(1, i).Value = Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(1, j).Value Then

            '''If header matches in both excels then copy column to destination excel'''
             'This is working but entire column copied
             Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Columns(i)
            '' This dosent work
            'Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(l2Row, j)).Copy Destination:=Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(l1Row, i)) 


        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You must paste to a Cell/Range and since you are copying a whole column, you must paste it on the first row of the target column.

```
Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Cells(1, i)
```

Comment: Thank you for that Ricardo. But I am want to copy and paste range I mean wb2.worksheets(Sheetname).Range(cells(2,j),cells(l2Row,j)).copy. This should copy from 2row to end of the rows in that column j. And then paste it to wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(cells(2,i),cells(l1Row,i)).pastespecial . This should paste the range to another excel from 2nd row. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Columns(j).Copy Destination:=Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Columns(i)
```

To:

```
Wb2.Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(Chr(j + 64) & "2:" & Chr(j + 64) & Wb2.Cells(Wb2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Wb1.Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(Chr(i + 64) & "2")
```

Comment: Hi zac thanks for that. I think my question is confusing everyone. I am assigning i and j  as variables to the column number where it matches other excel header. I am looping through i and j. So I need a way to put column index in range instead of actual column letter. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Wrote my comment on the wrong answer.. but here its is :)

Comment: Thank you zac . You are my superstar. Perfectly working . Thank you

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer